# Why Does Client Freeze When Sending Object To Server?

Tags: java, networking, client, freeze, send

I am writing a client/server game where the server can connect to multiple clients. When the clients connect to the server they each get an individual `Thread` to run on using a ThreadPool. They communicate with each other by sending Objects over ObjectInput and ObjectOutput Streams.

**My problem is this, when a client tries to send an Object, the client freezes.** The Server is fine and can still listen and receive new connections. What can I do to try and fix this?

*Code:*

Server Listening:

```
public void startServer() {
    if (running)
        return;
    else
        running = true;

    serverThread = new Thread(() -> {
        // Setup variables
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        ServerSocketChannel server = null;

        try {
            // Setup server
            server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8189));

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // Get client connection and run clientHandler
                SocketChannel clientConnection = server.accept();
                ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler(clientConnection);
                threadPool.execute(client);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            threadPool.shutdownNow();
            try {
                server.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
        }
    });
    serverThread.start();
}
```

Server Handling Connection:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(incoming));
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(incoming));

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            Request request = (Request) in.readObject();
            executeCmd(request);
        }

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
            in.close();
            incoming.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Client making connection and sending object:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    myThread = Thread.currentThread();

    try {
        this.connection = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT));

        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(connection));
        this.in = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(connection));
        isConnected = true;

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            Response rep = (Response) in.readObject();
        }

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        isConnected = false;
        System.err.println("Could not connect...");
    }
}

public static void changeName(String name) {
    Request req = new Request(RequestType.nameChange);
    req.setData(name);

    try {
        // This is when it freezes
        out.writeObject(req);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ClientConnection.name = name;
}
```

The `changeName(String name)` function is called when the player clicks on a JButton. The program takes the text value from a JTextField and passes it as the 'name' argument.

My program doesn't throw any Exceptions and the server never gets past `Request request = (Request) in.readObject();` for any client. Does it have something to do with me using [SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) instead of just [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html). If you have an answer please let me know.

**Edit:**

*Thread Dump Blocked Thread:*
[image: Here]

*Client Main Class:*

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               ClientDisplay.createClientDisplay();
           }
       });
   }
}
```

*Button that calls* `changeName(String name)`:

```
JButton confirm = new JButton("Submit");
    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!ClientConnection.isConnected()) {
                nameTitle.setForeground(Color.red);
                nameTitle.setText("Not Connected!");
                return;
            }
            
            // This would be where I call the method that freezes
            ClientConnection.changeName(nameField.getText());
            ClientDisplay.setScreen(new ChooseScreen());
        }
    });
```

Comment: The `while` loop in the client code won't exit until the thread is interrupted. Does something ever interrupt that thread? Please show that code. This code also ignores the response from the server (assigns it to an unused variable).

Comment: @Tim The client will get interrupted when the user clicks on a JButton that calls the getMyThead() method on the Client class, and then .interrupt() method once it has the thread. And I can't process the response from the server because the client cant send a request. When it does try it freezes. If you still wanna see more code I can post some more.

Comment: Yes, it would be good to see more of the client code. It's not clear how many threads are in use or how they interact. It would also be very helpful to show a thread dump of the client when it is frozen. https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump

Comment: @TimMoore I have add more code and an image of a part of the thread dump that says it is blocked. I'm going to try to change the clients socket from **SocketChannel** to just **Socket**, to see if that will help. If it does I will post my code here for anyone who needs it.

Comment: It is because you are doing multi-threaded I/O using streams derived from channels. It is a little-known feature that these reads and writes are synchronized against each other. Switching to a `Socket` will fix it. Or else get rid of the multithreading, have the server respond directly to each request, and have the client read the response after sending the request, all in the same thread. I'm not a big fan of multithreaded I/O on a single socket.

Comment: @user207421 Could you elaborate on what you said a bit more. So if I'm using a *Channel* I have to wait for the read or write operation to finish before I can read or write again. Why is this?

Comment: Because they are `synchronized` against each other. I already said that.